# got some weird things happening with same font on different Screen and OS Version

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface

i got some weird things for set typeface to the textview.
i have used same font file and give same typeface to the textview but problem is in different screen and android os version i got different view

run in android os 4.0.3  like

[image: here letter g, w, show differnt]

the original run pic of android os 4.1.2 in there i got not any problem of above font view

[image: [here letter g, w, show Perfect]

so give me solution for this and is this os dependent??
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

On the `TextView` set this:

```
txtView.setPaintFlags(txtView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: i have tired this but i can not get solution regard my problem there is same weird things set typeface to the textview as per above 4.0.3 os pic.

Comment: Not sure I can help, but you'll need to provide code so that people can see exactly what you are doing.